# Additional section in custom post type permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I'm trying to achieve add an extra section to a custom post type permalink. I'm sure this should be really easy but I'm struggling to get it working.

The extra section doesn't really need to do anything; it just needs to be there for tracking purposes. So, I don't need it to be a taxonomy or anything like that.

The URL structure I currently have is:

```
/properties/property-name
```

and what I need it to be is:

```
/properties/development-name/property-name
```

where "development-name" is the static bit which can effectively be ignored.

At the moment every time I go to `http://example.com/properties/development-name/property-name` it just redirects to `http://example.com/properties/property-name`.

This is my CPT setup:

```
function cpt_properties() {

    $labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Properties', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Property', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New Property' , 'properties'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Property'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Property'),
    'new_item' => __('New Property'),
    'all_items' => __('All Properties'),
    'view_item' => __('View Properties'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Properties'),
    'not_found' =>  __('No Properties found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Properties found in Trash'), 
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => __('Properties')

    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true, 
        'show_in_menu' => true, 
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => false,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' )
    ); 

    register_post_type('properties', $args);
}
add_action( 'init', 'cpt_properties' );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will *development-name* ever change? If so, where is it coming from?